# ExpressJS and Mongoose use create multiple times with a for function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

On the site I am creating, users can enter different tags and separate them with commas. ExpressJS should then search through whether they exist or not. If they do not exist, then it should create an object for each of them. I have an array and am iterating through it with a for function, however, only one object is created thanks to the callback... Is there any possible way to create multiple objects at once depending on the array's length?

```
for (i=0;i<postTopics.length;i++) {
    var postTopic = postTopics[i],
        postTopicUrl = postTopic.toString().toLowerCase().replace(' ', '-');

    Topic.findOne({ "title": postTopics[i] }, function (err, topic) {

        if (err) throw err;

        if (!topic) {

            Topic.create({
                title: postTopic,
                url: postTopicUrl

            }, function (err, topic) {

                if (err) throw err;

                res.redirect('/');
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Instead of finding one Topic at a time, why not query them all, and loop through that result?

Comment: Can you show me an example? Either way I would end up with the same result, as creating the topics has a callback function.

Comment: Firstly do you have a unique index on your topics? If so you could just make one DB call to create and ignore the duplicate error saving you the findOne call. Secondly you are responding with a redirect on the first response from a create call, you should be waiting until all asynchronous mongo requests have responded.

Answer (score 1):

Try out [`async.parallel`](https://github.com/caolan/async#paralleltasks-callback).

> $ npm install async

```
// Get the async module so we can do our parallel asynchronous queries much easier.
var async = require('async');

// Create a hash to store your query functions on.
var topicQueries = {};

// Loop through your postTopics once to create a query function for each one.
postTopics.forEach(function (postTopic) {
    // Use postTopic as the key for the query function so we can grab it later.
    topicQueries[postTopic] = function (cb) {
        // cb is the callback function passed in by async.parallel. It accepts err as the first argument and the result as the second.
        Topic.findOne({ title: postTopic }, cb);
    };
});

// Call async.parallel and pass in our topicQueries object.
// If any of the queries passed an error to cb then the rest of the queries will be aborted and this result function will be called with an err argument.
async.parallel(topicQueries, function (err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;

    // Create an array to store our Topic.create query functions. We don't need a hash because we don't need to tie the results back to anything else like we had to do with postTopics in order to check if a topic existed or not.
    var createQueries = [];

    // All our parallel queries have completed.
    // Loop through postTopics again, using postTopic to retrieve the resulting document from the results object, which has postTopic as the key.
    postTopics.forEach(function (postTopic) {
        // If there is no document at results[postTopic] then none was returned from the DB.
        if (results[postTopic]) return;

        // I changed .replace to use a regular expression. Passing a string only replaces the first space in the string whereas my regex searches the whole string.
        var postTopicUrl = postTopic.toString().toLowerCase().replace(\ \g, '-');

        // Since this code is executing, we know there is no topic in the DB with the title you searched for, so create a new query to create a new topic and add it to the createQueries array.
        createQueries.push(function (cb) {
            Topic.create({
                title: postTopic,
                url: postTopicUrl
            }, cb);
        });
    });

    // Pass our createQueries array to async.parallel so it can run them all simultaneously (so to speak).
    async.parallel(createQueries, function (err, results) {
        // If any one of the parallel create queries passes an error to the callback, this function will be immediately invoked with that err argument.
        if (err) throw err;

        // If we made it this far, no errors were made during topic creation, so redirect.
        res.redirect('/');
    });
});
```

First we create an object called `topicQueries` and we attach a query function to it for each `postTopic` title in your `postTopics` array. Then we pass the completed `topicQueries` object to `async.parallel` which will run each query and gather the results in a `results` object.

The `results` object ends up being a simple object hash with each of your `postTopic` titles as the key, and the value being the result from the DB. The `if (results[postTopic]) return;` line returns if `results` has no document under that `postTopic` key. Meaning, the code below it only runs if there was no topic returned from the DB with that title. If there was no matching topic then we add a query function to our `createQueries` array.

We don't want your page to redirect after just one of those new topics finishes saving. We want to wait until all your create queries have finished, so we use `async.parallel` yet again, but this time we use an array instead of an object hash because we don't need to tie the results to anything. When you pass an array to `async.parallel` the `results` argument will also be an array containing the results of each query, though we don't really care about the results in this example, only that no errors were thrown. If the `parallel` function finishes and there is no `err` argument then all the topics finished creating successfully and we can finally redirect the user to the new page.

PS - If you ever run into a similar situation, except each subsequent query requires data from the query before it, then checkout [`async.waterfall`](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) :)

[image]

Comment: My answer assumes `title` does not have a unique index in your model. As adamK pointed out, if you have a unique index on the title field for your topic documents then you can simply call `Topic.create` for every `postTopic` and ignore the error when it complains about duplicate entries. You can then use `async.parallel` just once to wait for all the create queries to finish. Just keep in mind that you'll likely have to invoke `cb` yourself if you're trying to ignore an error because if an `err` gets passed to async it will abort and immediately pass the error to the result function.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to see if things exist already and avoid getting errors on duplicates then the [`.create()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create) method already accepts a list. You don't seem to care about getting the document created in response so just check for the documents that are there and send in the new ones.

So with "finding first", run the tasks in succession. `async.waterfall` just to pretty the indent creep:

```
// Just a placeholder for your input
var topics = ["A Topic","B Topic","C Topic","D Topic"];

async.waterfall(
  [
    function(callback) {
      Topic.find(
        { "title": { "$in": topics } },
        function(err,found) {

          // assume ["Topic B", "Topic D"] are found
          found = found.map(function(x) {
            return x.title;
          });

          var newList = topics.filter(function(x) {
            return found.indexOf(x) == -1;
          });

          callback(err,newList);

        }
      );

    },
    function(newList,callback) {

      Topic.create(
        newList.map(function(x) {
          return {
            "title": x,
            "url": x.toString().toLowerCase().replace(' ','-')
          };
        }),
        function(err) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log("done");
          callback();
        }
      );
    }
  ]

);
```

You could move the "url" generation to a "pre" save schema hook. But again if you really don't need the validation rules, go for "bulk API" operations provided your target MongoDB and mongoose version is new enough to support this, which really means getting a handle to the underlying driver:

```
// Just a placeholder for your input
var topics = ["A Topic","B Topic","C Topic","D Topic"];

async.waterfall(
  [
    function(callback) {
      Topic.find(
        { "title": { "$in": topics } },
        function(err,found) {

          // assume ["Topic B", "Topic D"] are found
          found = found.map(function(x) {
            return x.title;
          });

          var newList = topics.filter(function(x) {
            return found.indexOf(x) == -1;
          });

          callback(err,newList);

        }
      );

    },
    function(newList,callback) {

      var bulk = Topic.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
      newList.forEach(function(x) {
        bullk.insert({
          "title": x,
          "url": x.toString().toLowerCase().replace(' ','-')
        });
      });
      bulk.execute(function(err,results) {
        console.log("done");
        callback();
      });

    }
  ]
);
```

That is a single write operation to the server, though of course all inserts are actually done in order and checked for errors.

Otherwise just hang the errors from duplicates and insert as an "unordered Op", check for "non duplicate" errors after if you want:

```
// Just a placeholder for your input
var topics = ["A Topic","B Topic","C Topic","D Topic"];

var bulk = Topic.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
topics.forEach(function(x) {
  bullk.insert({
    "title": x,
    "url": x.toString().toLowerCase().replace(' ','-')
  });
});
bulk.execute(function(err,results) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(results,undefined,4));
});
```

Output in results looks something like the following indicating the "duplicate" errors, but does not "throw" the error as this is not set in this case:

```
{
    "ok": 1,
    "writeErrors": [
        {
            "code": 11000,
            "index": 1,
            "errmsg": "insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: test.topic.$title_1  dup key: { : \"B Topic\" }",
            "op": {
                "title": "B Topic",
                "url": "b-topic",
                "_id": "53b396d70fd421057200e610"
            }
        },
        {
            "code": 11000,
            "index": 3,
            "errmsg": "insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: test.topic.$title_1  dup key: { : \"D Topic\" }",
            "op": {
                "title": "D Topic",
                "url": "d-topic",
                "_id": "53b396d70fd421057200e612"
            }
        }
    ],
    "writeConcernErrors": [],
    "nInserted": 2,
    "nUpserted": 0,
    "nMatched": 0,
    "nModified": 0,
    "nRemoved": 0,
    "upserted": []
}
```

Note that when using the native collection methods, you need to take care that a connection is already established. The mongoose methods will "queue" up until the connection is made, but these will not. More of a testing issue unless there is a chance this would be the first code executed.

Hopefully versions of those bulk operations will be exposed in the mongoose API soon, but the general back end functionality does depend on having MongoDB 2.6 or greater on the server. Generally it is going to be the best way to process.

Of course, in all but the last sample which does not need this, you can go absolutely "async nuts" by calling versions of "filter", "map" and "forEach" that exist under that library. Likely not to be a real issue unless you are providing really long lists for input though.

The [`.initializeOrderedBulkOP()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#initializeorderedbulkop) and [`.initializeUnorderedBulkOP()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#initializeunorderedbulkop) methods are covered in the node native driver manual. Also see the main manual for general descriptions of [Bulk operations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/).